# TypeError: existsSync is not a function for React js application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I noticed one weird behavior when I was using React js.

I used create-react-app to create a React js app. Then I installed one NPM package called youtube-dl for my React js application. And I put

```
const youtubedl = require("youtube-dl");
```

Then I got TypeError: existsSync is not a function.

I really searched a lot for this and I couldn't find a solution for React js application. Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: AFAIK that's a NodeJS package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

existsSync is a node function, so it looks like you've added a module intended for server-side/backend use, rather than for use inside your React app.

Comment: I see... Then there is no way to use it in my react app??

Comment: I'm afraid not, as it's designed to work with Node's functions and file system interfaces. Node.js is a server-side js platform, and so doesn't work with the browser directly at all (Electron brings the two together as a self-contained app, though). But with this you could have a React front end (for example), and have a Nodejs API (e.g. Express, Koa, Hapi) using this to download on the server, before sending it on to the client for download.